# Maven project with 180 POMs -- is this a code smell?

Tags: java, scala, maven, build

We have a large, 15 year-old, monolithic Java/Scala application that we build using Maven 3.  The build is complex, having many sub-projects nested hierarchically.  It works successfully, but takes 10 minutes (without tests) to do full build.  I think we're up to 180 `pom.xml` files, with a fair number of dependencies.

Of course we're working to extract services that can build, deploy, and run independently -- this will be a multi-year project.

Until then, are there guidelines, best practices, on how to structure the build as projects get larger?

Comment: 180 `poms`? I think you should start by removing unused/overlapping dependencies.

Comment: [Obligatory xkcd](https://xkcd.com/303/).

Comment: I would consider switching to Gradle as a first step (not an easy one, but doable) - which would make your build code much more composable and easy to work with, and might also offer some optimization opportunities (would probably perform better out-of-the-box, see https://gradle.org/gradle-vs-maven-performance/).

Comment: Well, it depends in what context we are referring here, in my opinion 180 pom's form a multi module project, each focusing on solving a specific problem or a functionality and others act as common utilities. Whoever designed it wanted to separate out the responsibilities into multiple modules, which they thought is cleaner a decade ago and others might have followed it blindly thereafter, adding new pom for each new project. I suggest that you consolidate the projects defining what they have in common and what problems they solve. When you have it I suggest you follow read my next comment.

Comment: apply microservice architecture http://microservices.io/patterns/microservices.html from what I understand with count of 180 pom's, is the number one reason you could be having a lot of processes that may be connected to but not dependent on each other. We need to understand that microservices are progressive successors of multi module projects. One of the projects that I worked 10 years back has about 18 pom's people loved this design for a while as it was separating logic, functionality and concerns. As I said consolidate the similar projects, eliminate unwanted and in house build libraries.

Comment: http://microservices.io/i/MicroservicePatternLanguage.jpg this is a great blog about the micro-services patterns

Comment: Microservice architecture is good for some use cases and bad for others. Microservices destroy the possibility of global transactions, which is the main reason that we cannot apply them for the backend software in our company.

Comment: Awesome comments -- thanks.  TzachZohar Yeah, used Gradle before -- it's better for sure.  NiVeR yes, first step was to remove all the unneeded bits.  @VikramPalakurthi -- agree this is an explosion of what was a good idea 10 years ago!  We know what should be services (and indeed, the services are getting extracted as we go), so my question was oriented around what we should tackle first.  Thanks for the help on my overly general question, to all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I think this question is too broad for this format.)

I can recommend the "Working Effectively with Legacy Code" book by Michael Feathers for this kind of situation. It has excellent advice and recipes for dealing with the kind of codebase you describe. I was in a similar situation and found it very useful.

Comment: I agree that this is an overly broad/opinion question.  Your answer and comments above are what I was looking for.  Thanks!